# Disable a driver with a command

Tags: drivers, mouse, automation, autohotkey

I have a macbook running Windows on it (with bootcamp). I have external mouse to use, but touchpad remains enabled at the same time. So when I use keyboard, I always click on it and move mouse cursor.

The first thing I did is I just disabled driver in devmgmt.msc. But sometimes it could be helpful to disable and enable the driver with AutoHotKey (mapping ^F12 key or whatever).

So I just want to know, is there any way of enabling/disabling the driver with a command or registry? In order to be able to do that with AutoHotKey.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Devcon`, but it's not part of standard distribution, you would need to download WDK (Windows Driver Kit) and extract the tool. 
This article details it's functionality and also links to download/installation instructions.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-manage-device-drivers-with-command-line.aspx

From that article:

> Features (also Pros):
>
> All device and driver management functionality that can be found in Device Management MMC including advanced functionality such as:
>           Disable device
>           Select one specific driver for specific device from the list of compatible drivers that are currently installed in the system
>
> Cons:
>
> Not available out-of-the box
>       Syntax complexity is high

*Disclaimer: I have not used it.*